# Java For Loop Increment or Decrement Based on Condition

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach, iterator

I have two methods that are identical except for the loop index direction.

The loop in `methodA` expects `indexBegin < indexEnd` so it increments i from indexBegin up to indexEnd.

The loop in `methodB` expects `indexBegin > indexEnd` so it decrements i from indexBegin down to indexEnd.

```
public void methodA(int indexBegin, int indexEnd, List<Double> values) {
 for (int i = indexBegin; i <= indexEnd; i++) {
  ...
 }
}

public void methodB(int indexBegin, int indexEnd, List<Double> values) {
 for (int i = indexBegin; i >= indexEnd; i--) {
  ...
 }
}
```

Is there a way to consolidate the looping logic here using an Iterator so I only have a single method?  I still need to keep track of the indexes.

Comment: Just change the values of indexBegin and indexEnd as well as the increment value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java-8 you can use [IntStream.iterate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) or [Stream.iterate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) with the combination of `limit` to generate sequence in increment or decrement order, So you can have one method by passing `IntStream` as argument

```
public void utilMethod(IntStream range, List<Double> values) {
   range.forEach(i->i);
 }
```

or

```
 public void utilMethod(Stream<Integer> range, List<Double> values) {
   range.forEach(i->i);
 }
```

**Example :**

```
IntStream.iterate(0,i->i+1).limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);

IntStream.iterate(10,i->i-1).limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
```

From java-9 you can use overloaded [IntStream.iterate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntPredicate-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) or [Stream.iterate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) to generate sequence in increment or decrement order

```
public void utilMethod(IntStream range, List<Double> values) {
   range.forEach(i->i);
 }
```

**Example**

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i->i<10, i->i+1).forEach(System.out::println);

IntStream.iterate(10, i->i>0, i->i-1).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you change to a while loop and declare both? That way you can access either one in the method.

```
int countingUp = indexBegin;
int countingDown = indexEnd;

while (countingUp < indexEnd) {
  . . .

  countingUp++;
  countingDown--;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator in the for loop like this:

```
   public void method(int indexBegin, int indexEnd, List<Double> values) {
       int direction = indexEnd - indexBegin ;
       for (int i = indexBegin; direction > 0 ? i<=indexEnd : i>=indexEnd; i= direction>0 ? i+1:i-1) {
          ...
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can select the indices such that you always iterate from the lower to the upper bound.

```java
int begin = indexBegin > indexEnd ? indexEnd : indexBegin;
int end = indexBegin > indexEnd ? indexBegin: indexEnd;

for (int i = begin ; i <= end ; i++) {
  ...
}
```